# mariadb main thread over 100% cpu and flushing logs

Tags: redhat, cpu-usage, mariadb, database-performance, threads

I have 5.5.60-MariaDB and noticed the main thread remains on sleep mode for the last 200hrs. After checking innodb status I see the below line for this thread.

Main thread process no. 119014, id 140084875732736, state: flushing log

pid 119014 is the main thread and the only one on S status when I look at htop, the others comes and goes without any problems, but its usage is around 100% CPU with 400% peaks.

Any idea on how to avoid this utilization and make this thread available?.

Its my first post here, so if my post is not complete please help me with it for future references.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you get from `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`?

Comment: Not much, I can see my pid many sleeping and 2 or 3 on query with simple things like a select or insert.

Comment: Please show `top` and `innotop` -- at least the first few lines (if sorted by CPU).